# Magento 2: Is there a way to use the include command into the di.xml?

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection

Is there a way to merge multiple `di.xml` files into one main `di.xml` configuration file?

I would like to split a big `di.xml` file into five different files. I have seen the include command in the `system.xml` file into the PayPal module and I am curious to know if I can split the `di.xml` file too.

Look at:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Paypal/etc/adminhtml/system.xml#L40-L43

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot split the `di.xml` file inside a module into multiple parts other than the ones supported by Magento.
All you have to work with is:

- etc/di.xml - the main di file. Loaded everytime.
- etc/frontend/di.xml - loaded only on frontend
- etc/adminhtml/di.xml - loaded only on backend.

The `include` tag in the `system.xml` files works because it is interpreted when the system.xml files are interpreted. So it is `system.xml` specific.
There is nothing similar for `di.xml` files.